# Modifying the content of a RichTextBox before it gets drawn

Tags: .net, winforms, richtextbox

How can I modify the data that is drawn on a `RichTextBox`?  I've tried overriding the `Text` property but it doesn't work.

Intercepting `WM_GETTEXT` and then modifying the `Text` property does work, but I lose all formatting information:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == WM_GETTEXT)
        {
            var currentText = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(m.LParam);

            // Modify the text
            currentText = currentText?.Replace("a", "b");
            this.Text = currentText;
        }
    }
```

Essentially I want to be able to intercept the RTF content before the control is painted, and then replace that RTF with something else.  I've tried intercepting `EM_STREAMOUT` but it doesn't seem to be called when the content changes.

Comment: Have you run this code in debug?

Comment: What do you mean?  Have I debugged it?  Yes.